# calling IBAction button inside IBAction?

Tags: swift, random, ibaction

I got this IBAction that shuffles a pack of cards randomly

```
@IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    cardNamesArray = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(cardNamesArray) as! [String]
    cardNamesArray2 = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(cardNamesArray2) as! [String]



    let firstCardString:String = self.cardNamesArray[0]
    self.FirstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)

    let SecondCardString:String = self.cardNamesArray2[1]
    self.SecondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: SecondCardString)
    }
```

...and this part of the code scores a point when the cards match, however when they macth I need to it to shuffle again. Can I use IBAction  playRoundTapped inside IBAction snapButtonTapped?

```
@IBAction func SnapButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {


        if firstRandomNumber == SecondRandomNumber {

        print("index match")

        self.playerScore += 1
        self.playerScoreLabel.text = String(self.playerScore)

        cardNamesArray.removeAtIndex(firstRandomNumber)
        cardNamesArray2.removeAtIndex(SecondRandomNumber)

            if cardNamesArray.count == 0 && cardNamesArray2.count == 0{


                print("user won")
                //alert box
                let alert = UIAlertController(title:"Level completed", message: "Your score is \(playerScore)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"next level", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true, completion:nil)

            }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. An IBAction is just a method with a specific signature and a tag that tells Interface Builder it can be connected to controls. You are free to call it yourself.

Comment: How would you call it in my case playRoundTapped inside snapButtonTapped?

Comment: @Sam `self.playRoundTapped(self.buttonReference)`

Comment: I tried 'self.playRoundTapped(self.playRoundButton)' and it works but it just messes up the cards, is there another way I can make the cards shuffle when they are matched.

Comment: You haven't really told us enough about your app in order for us to help with shuffling the cards without messing them up. That's a separate problem.